# Sort JSON Dictionary by Value

Tags: python, json, sorting, dictionary, json-value

How can I organize this JSON file in descending order by value?

```
{
     "48275928194813456218": 12,
     "57532478653456645734": 26
}
// And sort that into:
{
     "57532478653456645734": 26,
     "48275928194813456218": 12
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
sortedDict = sorted(myDictionary, key=lambda i: int(i), reverse=True)
```

But this messes with the JSON file and throws errors...can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: No, because that's sorted by key not value

Comment: Oops, that should've been [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613183)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

I needed to make my code this:

```
sortedDict = dict(sorted(myDictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
```